# Why I receive This Notice While I make checking by array_key_exist

Tags: php

Please tell me why I receive this message While I use array_key_exists?

```
 <td width="91">'.(array_key_exists ( 1 , $famstand )) ? $famstand[1] : "" .'</td>
```

Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Seems like your $famstand array does not have two variables

Comment: @AroshaDeSilva Then why does `array_key_exists(1, $famstand)` return `true`?

Comment: can you show a var_dump on $famstand array ?

Comment: array:1 [
  2 => "x"
]  it have to be false in this case

Comment: Side note, if you are using PHP 7+, you can use `($famstand[1] ?? "")` to do this. (Still needs to be enclosed in parentheses for the same reason Barmar explained.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is operator precedence. `.` has higher precedence than `:?`, so this is being parsed as:

```
('<td width="91">'.(array_key_exists ( 1 , $famstand ))) ? $famstand[1] : "" .'</td>'
```

The concanetation returns a non-empty string, which is truthy, even though the key doesn't exist, so it's trying to access the array element.

Add parentheses around the tertiary:

```
<td width="91">'.(array_key_exists(1 , $famstand) ? $famstand[1] : "") .'</td>
```

Comment: Yes it is true That you saying :)) Thanks